# Remove Chrome header and footer in prints, with multiple pages

Tags: css, pdf-generation, chromium

We have multi-page HTML documents that we need to print (actually save to PDF) using a Chromium embedded in a PowerBuilder application. The documents are tax receipts for charitable donations, and as such, should not have headers and footers, which would look really weird and unprofessional to the donors.

I have found a lot of solutions using CSS and @media print rules to eliminate the page headers and footers (by setting the @page margin to 0), with additional CSS to get the margins back (setting them on the body) but they only work when there's only a single page! The top and bottom margins on the body in those rules apply to the top of the first page and bottom of the last page - but the bottom of the first page and top of the 2nd page (etc.) all still have margins of 0! That's not acceptable.

Surely there must be a good solution to this?

Yes, you can do it with headless Chrome (in fact, we **were** doing it that way) but we are running this in a Citrix-like environment (Graphon actually) and for some reason calling the Chrome executable recently just stopped working (it hangs and has to be killed)! So we need a different solution for converting HTML to PDF, and this seems like our best option - if only we can get rid of the headers and footers.

Any solutions - thanks?

Comment: I recommend you to show at least one image.

Comment: I'm sorry, no, those headers and footers are added directly by Chrome when it prints or saves to PDF, not by a printer driver. There is an option in the Chrome UI, and in its headless command line, to skip adding them, but I cannot find any way in embedded Chromium to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Was struggling to find a solution to the same problem for quite a while, and didn't want to leave hiding the default header and footer to the user.

I still ended up using no margins, and a table.

Thead and tfoot are repeated on all pages, so I added an extra "hidden" row above actual table headers and since I wasn't using a footer made a row for it.

Setting the height and hiding those extra rows allow it to function as margins.

Tested it in Chrome and it worked well enough for my case.

```css
.hidden * {
  height: 5mm;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  /* uncomment */
  background-color: red;
  /* delete */
  color: white;
  /* delete */
}

@media print {
  @page {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  #datatable tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: auto;
  }
  #datatable td {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>thead hidden row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Table header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="hidden">
    <tr>
      <td>tfoot hidden row</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>. . .</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[How it shows up in print preview in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwY8H.jpg)

Trying to nest tables or divs inside thead rows seems to break something and it prevents it from showing up at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @page {
    size: atuo; /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 24px;
    @top-left {
        content: normal;
    }
    @bottom-center { 
        content: element(footer);
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?